# undefined method `each' for #<SoundCloud::Client:0x87288f0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I hope someone can help, 
 i can connect to soundcloud and get a list of items but it is just a bunch of text. when i try to order it in a list a get the error "undefined method `each' for #SoundCloud::Client:0x87288f0>"

**soundcloud controller:**

```
def self.search
  @client = Soundcloud.new(:client_id => ENV["SOUNDCLOUD_CLIENT_ID"])
end
```

**search.html.erb**

```
<!--this works-->
<%= @client.get('/tracks', :q => 'some user') %>

<!--this does not-->
<% @client.each do |s| %>
    <ul>
        <li><%= s.get('/tracks', :q => 'some user') %></li>
    </ul>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<% @client.get('/tracks', :q => 'some user').each do |track| %>
    <ul>
        <li><%= track.title %></li>
    </ul>
<% end %>
```

`@client.get('/tracks', :q => 'some user')` returns a collection of `track` objects which can be enumerated.

By themselves `track` objects are not enumerable and that is why you are getting error when trying to call `.each` method on one of them.